# how to use Jsoup to put text in different lines

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to extract data from a website and appending it to a text box in my application. I want when the codes find a full stop in the text then it changes line. How can i do this with jsoup? Is there any method for this?
Here is my code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("link here").get();
org.jsoup.select.Elements els = doc.select("p"+"\r\n");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {
sb.append(el.text());}
txtArea.setText(sb.toString());
txtArea.setLineWrap(true);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want I think that you should select like this:

```
doc.select("p")
```

and then append like this

```
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : els) {
    sb.append(el.text());
    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

But I am not sure what you meant by "when the codes find a full stop in the text"

Comment: is line.sperator a method?

Comment: no. it is string name for system (environment) property. On unix System.getProperty("line.separator") will return \n, on windows there are two \r\n, on macs \r. History is cruel sometimes. Is it working like you wanted?

Comment: No its not working.plz help me. Nothing is happening. There is no line break after a sentence.